# The error "Call to undefined method" appears every minute after running the job

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks

I have a class that gets data from the API and saves it to the DB. I also have a command that creates a job and assigns it to a queue. The job itself calls the sync() method of the class that receives data from the API.

After executing the command, the job successfully executed, but **laravel.log** now shows an error every minute.

```
production.ERROR: Call to undefined method
    App\Services\Odata\OdataSyncStoragesService::getName() 
{"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): 
Call to undefined method App\\Services\\Odata\\OdataSyncStoragesService::getName() at
 /var/www/fastuser/data/www/89.191.229.227/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Schedule.php:138)
```

The same error appears when executing the **schedule:list** command
OdataSyncStoragesService.php

I'm working on a project someone else has already done. The project already has an infrastructure where classes like OdataSync****Service are made according to one template.

It is noteworthy that other classes I have made based on OdataSync****Service work and do not give this error. It is also unclear why it is every minute.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Odata;

use App\Models\OdataStorage;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use Throwable;

class OdataSyncStoragesService extends OdataBaseService
{

    const URL_STORAGES = "Catalog_Склады";

    /**
     * Синхронизация атрибутов
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws GuzzleException
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    public function sync(): void
    {
        $storages = $this->fetchStorages();

        foreach ($storages as $storage) {
            $parsedStorage = $this->parseStorage($storage);
            OdataStorage::updateOrCreate([
                'Ref_Key' => $parsedStorage['Ref_Key']
            ],$parsedStorage);
        }
    }

    private function parseStorage(array $storage) {
        return [
            'Ref_Key' => $storage['Ref_Key'],
            'DataVersion' => $storage['DataVersion'],
            'DeletionMark' => $storage['DeletionMark'],
            'Parent_Key' => $storage['Parent_Key'],
            'IsFolder' => $storage['IsFolder'],
            'Description' => $storage['Description'],
            'groupSelection' => $storage['ВыборГруппы'],
            'useAddressStorage' => $storage['ИспользоватьАдресноеХранение'],
            'useReferenceAddressStorage' => $storage['ИспользоватьАдресноеХранениеСправочно'],
            'useOrderSchemeOnShipment' => $storage['ИспользоватьОрдернуюСхемуПриОтгрузке'],
            'useOrderSchemeOnSurplusShortageReflection' => $storage['ИспользоватьОрдернуюСхемуПриОтраженииИзлишковНедостач'],
            'useOrderSchemeOnReceipt' => $storage['ИспользоватьОрдернуюСхемуПриПоступлении'],
            'useItemSeries' => $storage['ИспользоватьСерииНоменклатуры'],
            'useWarehouseRooms' => $storage['ИспользоватьСкладскиеПомещения'],
            'calendar_Key' => $storage['Календарь_Key'],
            'controlOperationalBalances' => $storage['КонтролироватьОперативныеОстатки'],
            'addressStorageSettings' => $storage['НастройкаАдресногоХранения'],
            'department_Key' => $storage['Подразделение_Key'],
            'businessRegion_Key' => $storage['БизнесРегион_Key'],
            'retailPriceType_Key' => $storage['РозничныйВидЦены_Key'],
            'currentResponsiblePosition' => $storage['ТекущаяДолжностьОтветственного'],
            'currentResponsible_Key' => $storage['ТекущийОтветственный_Key'],
            'warehouseType' => $storage['ТипСклада'],
            'serviceLevel' => $storage['УровеньОбслуживания'],
            'priceType_Key' => $storage['УчетныйВидЦены_Key'],
            'startShipmentAfterTransportTaskCreation' => $storage['НачинатьОтгрузкуПослеФормированияЗаданияНаПеревозку'],
            'useWorkAreas' => $storage['ИспользованиеРабочихУчастков'],
            'priceInformationSourceForPrinting' => $storage['ИсточникИнформацииОЦенахДляПечати'],
            'useIssueOrderStatuses' => $storage['ИспользоватьСтатусыРасходныхОрдеров'],
            'useReceiptOrderStatuses' => $storage['ИспользоватьСтатусыПриходныхОрдеров'],
            'useGoodsRevaluationStatuses' => $storage['ИспользоватьСтатусыПересчетовТоваров'],
            'orderSchemeStartDateOnShipment' => $storage['ДатаНачалаОрдернойСхемыПриОтгрузке'],
            'orderSchemeStartDateOnReceipt' => $storage['ДатаНачалаОрдернойСхемыПриПоступлении'],
            'orderSchemeStartDateOnSurplusShortageReflection' => $storage['ДатаНачалаОрдернойСхемыПриОтраженииИзлишковНедостач'],
            'warehouseUsageStartDate' => $storage['ДатаНачалаИспользованияСкладскихПомещений'],
            'inventoryStorageStartDate' => $storage['ДатаНачалаАдресногоХраненияОстатков'],
            'considerCostBySeries' => $storage['УчитыватьСебестоимостьПоСериям'],
            'controlFreeBalances' => $storage['КонтролироватьСвободныеОстатки'],
            'responsibleStorage' => $storage['СкладОтветственногоХранения'],
            'luggageHolderType' => $storage['ВидПоклажедержателя'],
            'luggageHolder' => $storage['Поклажедержатель'],
            'luggageHolderTypeEnum' => $storage['Поклажедержатель_Type'],
            'storageResponsibilityPeriod' => $storage['СрокОтветственногоХранения'],
            'responsibleStorageUntilClaim' => $storage['ОтветственноеХранениеДоВостребования'],
            'specialMarks' => $storage['ОсобыеОтметки'],
            'goodsStorageConditions' => $storage['УсловияХраненияТоваров'],
            'workshopWarehouse' => $storage['ЦеховаяКладовая'],
            'orderPickingSupportedInStore' => $storage['ВМагазинеПоддерживаетсяСборкаЗаказов'],
            'deliveryByOwnCouriersSupportedInStore' => $storage['ВМагазинеПоддерживаетсяДоставкаСвоимиКурьерами'],
            'orderPickingRealizationMethod' => $storage['СпособСозданияРеализацииПриСборкеЗаказов'],
            'fiscalizationMethodOnDelivery' => $storage['СпособФискализацииПриДоставке'],
            'orderPickingAndDeliveryPerformedByOneEmployee' => $storage['СборкаИДоставкаВыполняетсяОднимСотрудником'],
            'couriersCanAssignOrdersToThemselves' => $storage['КурьерыМогутНазначатьСебеЗаказы'],
            'pickersCanAssignOrdersToThemselves' => $storage['СборщикиМогутНазначатьСебеЗаказы'],
            'orderDeliveryStandardPeriod' => $storage['НормативныйСрокДоставкиЗаказов'],
            'couriersUsePaymentTerminals' => $storage['КурьерыИспользуютЭквайринговыеТерминалы'],
            'couriersUseAutonomousCashRegisters' => $storage['КурьерыИспользуютАвтономныеККТ'],
            'orderPickingStartDate' => $storage['ДатаНачалаСборкиЗаказов'],
            'deliveryByOwnCouriersStartDate' => $storage['ДатаНачалаДоставкиСвоимиКурьерами'],
            'goodsGrouping' => $storage['ГруппировкаТоваров'],
            'individualPriceType_Key' => $storage['ИндивидуальныйВидЦены_Key'],
            'contactInformation' => json_encode($storage['КонтактнаяИнформация']),
            'additionalAttributes' => json_encode($storage['ДополнительныеРеквизиты']),
            'predefined' => $storage['Predefined'],
            'predefinedDataName' => $storage['PredefinedDataName'],
            'parentNavigationLinkUrl' => $storage['Parent@navigationLinkUrl'] ?? '',
            'departmentNavigationLinkUrl' => $storage['Подразделение@navigationLinkUrl'] ?? '',
            'retailPriceTypeNavigationLinkUrl' => $storage['РозничныйВидЦены@navigationLinkUrl'] ?? ''
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @param bool $onlyVersions
     * @return array|mixed
     * @throws GuzzleException
     */
    private function fetchStorages(): mixed
    {
        $params = [
            '$format' => 'json',
        ];

        $result = $this->sendRequest(self::URL_STORAGES, 'GET', $params);

        if (!$result['success']) {
            return [];
        }

        return $result['data']['value'] ?? [];
    }
}
```

Comment: include the class where this getName is called from

Comment: @krisgjika This class is imported by the "use" directive in the job.

Comment: That might be, but you need to show us some more code. The class `App\Services\Odata\OdataSyncStoragesService` itself seems to be "present", otherwise you would get an error saying that it can't find that class to begin with. But it appears not to have any such (static) `getName` method.

Comment: Exactly what code do I need to provide?

Comment: This is basic debugging, the error is 100% clear, it is trying to call `getName` but `OdataSyncStoragesService` does not have that method, so, share the full code of `OdataSyncStoragesService`...

Comment: There is no `getName` on `OdataSyncStoragesService`, maybe it is on the parent class `OdataBaseService`, you need to find where `getName` is defined

Comment: OdataBaseService has no methods named getName(). The children of this class also don’t have such methods, but they work.

Comment: where is the error being thrown, what file, what line? post the full stack trace